# How create a logic color drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, drawing

I'm looking for a way to create a logic color drawing like fill tool in photoshop or gimp or event paint...
Here is basically what I want to implement :
[image: enter image here] ---> [image]

Any suggestion on how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds/looks like you just need to implement a [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). There a few variations, from simple 4-direction to more complex 8-direction, though all work on a similar principle and are fairly easy to implement.

Here's a link to [a GameDev.SE post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12447/what-is-an-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm) that may be a good place to start and perhaps even a better place to post this question!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [flood fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)